# How to unmarshal with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

How to unmarshal the below xml file to java object can any one suggest me?

XML FILE:

```
<DATA>
 <ID>12345</ID>
 <NAME>Person1</NAME>
 <MAIL>sa@gmail.com</MAIL>
</DATA>
<DATA>
 <ID>12345</ID>
 <NAME>Person1</NAME>
 <MAIL>sa@gmail.com</MAIL>
</DATA>
```

POJO CLASS

```
@XmlRootElement("DATA")
@XmlType(preorder={"ID","NAME","MAIL"})
public class Unmarshall{

private int ID;
private String NAME;
private String MAIL

/*gettters and setters*/

}
```

If i am having one set of `<DATA> </DATA>` in the XML file ? i can able to unmarshal in to JAVA object if i am having more than one `<DATA></DATA>` am getting an exception can any one help me on this issue?

Comment: Proper XML files should only have 1 XMLRootElement. You will need to wrap your <DATA> tags in another tag.

Comment: @Steve, That XML is not generated by me, got that file from one different source. I need some data from that XML so only struggling.

Comment: The source generates invalid XML. As Steve replied, XML must have a single root element. You have invalid XML with 2 root elements and JAXB can't deserialize it. You can do a pre-processing logic where you may create a <DATASET> root element and include <DATA> elements in it.

Comment: I have deleted the tags "sax" and "saxon" since they appear to have no relevance to the question.